# Matplotlib agg complexity exceeding issue even with very small dataset

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing

I've been trying to get some data to display in a matplotlib graph and I'm having an issue that seems fairly unexpected. I was originally trying to plot a large number of data points (~500000) and was getting the

> `OverflowError: Agg rendering complexity exceeded. Consider downsampling or decimating your data.`

So, I did just that. I decimated my data using both the signal.decimate function and using slice notation. None of these solved my issue, I still get the complexity exceeded error even when trying to plot only 60 data points. I've attempted to determine if my computer my have some bad settings but I am fully capable of plotting  500000 points in a straight line without a hiccup. I'll add some example code and maybe someone can help me spot the error of my ways.

```
import scikits.audiolab as audiolab

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.signal import freqz

    sound = audiolab.sndfile('exampleFile.wav', 'read')
    sound_info = sound.read_frames(sound.get_nframes())
    sound.close()

    nsamples = sound_info.size
    t = np.linspace(0, 5, nsamples, endpoint=False)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(t, sound_info, label='Filtered signal (600 Hz)')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: OWW just 60 data points it is so small to get exceeded error, show us how you decimated your `sound_info`

Comment: I used signal.decimate() as well as sound_info = sound_info[::x] and ensured that the length of the data was shrinking.

Comment: could you provide your input file? Testing with linspace the border from which matplotlib would not plot anymore was about 169000 data points.

Comment: I'll see if I can get it added tomorrow when I get back to the computer I was working on. Hopefully it's just a simple error. I was quite surprised I was having such difficulty with it.

Comment: Apparently I've got it functioning now. No code changes, just a software update and a computer restart over the weekend and it decided to work. That's never a comforting feeling.